# the focus sticks on the shell and it Traverses by tab key no more

Tags: java, swt

I made a simple shell contents two buttons with SWT.
after compiling the code below, when I press tab key on the shell several times, the focus traverses from the button one to the button two and next goes on the shell (plane); and despite pressing tab key, the focus stays there, it traverses no more.
while the shell's style is NO_FOCUS.
could someone please tell me how this issue should be solve?

I am working with: Windows 10 64-bit, Java 8 64-bit, swt v4.7.3, Eclipse neon (java SEE developers),

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MainWindows {
MainWindows() {
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.CENTER | SWT.NO_FOCUS | SWT.TOP);
shell.setText("test win");
shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());
shell.setSize(500, 500);
Button b1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
Button b2 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
b1.setBounds(100, 100, 50, 50);
b2.setBounds(200, 200, 50, 50);
b1.setText("b1");
b2.setText("b2");
shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
}

display.dispose();
}
      static void main(String[] args) {
MainWindows mainWindows = new MainWindows();
}
}
```

Comment: Note: SWT.NO_FOCUS is not a valid style for `Shell`, Only the styles listed in the JavaDoc for Shell are supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, this issue occur because  Style SWT.CENTER has been used incorrectly as an argument of Shell constructor.
Style CENTER is constant for align center behavior that Used By widgets: Button Label TableColumn 
and FormAttachment in a FormLayout
reference: [Class SWT](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2FSWT.html)